# How to show resource view in sync-fusion angular gantt-chart

Tags: angular, syncfusion, gantt-chart, angular-gantt

[image: gantt-chart]

As shown in image, I'm expecting multiple task in same row using sync-fusion. any suggestion.
Using package @syncfusion/ej2-angular-gantt

Answer (score 1):

Currently, we don’t have support for Resource view. In EJ2 Gantt we have already logged a feature request for this. We will include resource view Gantt support in Volume 2, 2020 release and it will be available in the month of June, 2020. You can track the status of this feature by using below feedback report link. 
Feedback – https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/6402/resource-view-support-in-ej2-gantt

Regards, 
Karthikeyan Raja